# Save Swagger spec to file during Maven build

Tags: java, maven, swagger

I'm using the `swagger-jersey2-jaxrs` Maven plugin to serve my current Swagger spec file which works fine. Now I want to automate the generation of a Java client library to that specification, for example using the `swagger-codegen-maven-plugin` Maven plugin.

`swagger-codegen-maven-plugin` requires the path to the Swagger spec file as an argument. Is there a way to configure `swagger-jersey2-jaxrs` to store that spec file to disk? That way I could always generate the Java sources without having to download the spec file by hand and then starting the `swagger-codegen-maven-plugin` task.

I'm not sure if this is the way to go but I'm open to other approaches. The goal is to always have a Java client library that is in sync with the current state of implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest thing to do is have your build script spin up the server and point directly to that.